# GIS Application for online map and journey planner

Tags: web-mapping, routing, java

I am planning to implement an online map application with journey planner for a city. I don't have any experience in GIS development but I have a few years of experience in Java development.

So could you guys suggest me how I could start off my implementation. Any recommendation for books or documentations? What kind of technology stack should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your application targets a specific city or features some novel options, I would recommend first to go through the well-established software solutions, like Google Maps or Bing Maps. They both have good support for custom applications and custom extensibility using [JavaScript](http://video.google.de/videoplay?docid=6747013268718993918&q=programming%20google%20map%20api) (for Google Maps) and [Ajax](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/)/[Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/) (for Bing).

Then I would look to some already existing applications based upon these services, like [this one](http://www.komoot.de/).

And only then I would move to more specific stacks..

Comment: Thanks for the reply (I still can't upvote your post yet). I am planning to implement a map application with public bus guide. Can that kind of application be implemented using Google Map? (Google map doesn't support public transport feature for the city that I am referring of course)

Comment: Absolutely! Especially if your city has a good Google Map coverage (meaning that it finds correctly streets and house numbers) this task is doable. We even used Google Maps for a similar application for Ukraine, where the street coverage is much worse.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have Java experience, you might take a look at opengeo.org suite of applications. They have a free community edition available. http://opengeo.org/technology/suite/download/

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned public transportation (public bus guide), you might consider taking a look at [Open Trip Planner](http://opentripplanner.com/).

Tri-met, the local mass transit system in Portland, Oregon [is using OTP](http://portlandafoot.org/w/index.php?title=Open_Trip_Planner) and has been developing a lot of new functionality for it.